# Change date format like dd/mm/yy

Tags: lightning-web-components, date, lwc-dom, date-field

Here is my code,

I am trying to change date format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YY format.
How Can I resolve with this one? As well I am passing the value and label to the parent component that is also not working. Thanks in advance.

```
 @api label;
    uniqueId;
   connectedCallback() {
    // Increment the static variable to get a unique ID
    DateInputId += 1;
    // Set the unique ID property using the incremented value
    this.uniqueId = `date-input-${DateInputId}`;
}   
   // Handle the date change and propagate the event to the parent component
    handleDateChange(event) 
    {
        const selectedDate = event.target.value;
        console.log('Selected date ',selectedDate);
            // Dispatch a custom event to notify the parent
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { value: selectedDate } }));
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a valid date format. You don't need any processing converting to strings, splitting or anything. You can directly use [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). The format you need is actually India's locale date format. If your users will have `en-IN locale` you can directly convert it to required format with else pass the optional parameter as `en-IN`

(Works because my system locale is en-IN)

```
const dt = '2023-10-20';
new Date('2023-10-20').toLocaleDateString( {
  year: '2-digit',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
})

OUTPUT: 20/10/23
```

With en-IN locale param:

```
const dt = '2023-10-20';
new Date('2023-10-20').toLocaleDateString( 'en-IN', {
  year: '2-digit',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
})

OUTPUT: 20/10/23
```

Comment: Rather depends on the browser's configured locale. This may be appropriate but the OP did not clarify if this should be for specific users in a given locale. That said, I think this is definitely a better approach compared with hard-coding the format for all users (since your approach will work to present short form dates in any locale and avoid confusing the user if, e.g., they are from the US).

Answer (score 0):

```
handleDateChange(event) 
    {
        const selectedDate = event.target.value;
            // Dispatch a custom event to notify the parent
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { value: selectedDate } }));
            this.value = new Date(selectedDate);

          this.formatDate();
    }

         formatDate() {
          if (this.value instanceof Date ) //&& !isNaN(this.value)) 
          {
              const day = this.value.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
              const month = (this.value.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
              const year = this.value.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // Get the last two digits
              this.formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
              console.log('Selected date ',this.formattedDate);

          } else {
              // Handle invalid date
              this.formattedDate = '';  console.log('no date value');

          }
          // Dispatch a custom event to notify the parent
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', { detail: { value: this.formattedDate } }));
      }
```

Date format - > DD/MM/YY.